# Use $.get() inside success: function(data) {... in $.ajax().?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I use `$.get()` or `$.ajax()` inside of `success: function(data) {...` in `$.ajax()` ?

Like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/test1.html',
    success: function (data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
        $.get("test2.php", function (data) {
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
    }
});
```

Or

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/test1.html',
    success: function (data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/test2.html',
            success: function (data) {
                $('.result').html(data);
                alert('Load was performed.');
            }
        });
  }
});
```

Does this work correctly? Which of those is best? If it does not work, how would I do it correctly?

Comment: you might want to look at jquery deferends

Comment: I see no reason why this would not work - but since all the code is already there, why don't you just try it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do both.

The $.get() is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

See in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: $.ajax take get as the default, to make a post you could use the method attribute provided and specify its value as post.

Comment: Exactly. For that, you need to add the setting type, like type='POST', because 'GET' is the default value